# FATAL EXCEPTION: main. Error en adaptador RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Cuando intento ejecutar la aplicación en Android Studio me sale la excepción FATAL EXCEPTION: main, en la clase adaptador de un RecyclerView

```
public class PetAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PetAdapter.PetViewHolder> { //Linea del error
private ArrayList<Pet> pets;
private Activity activity;

//Constructor
public PetAdapter(ArrayList<Pet> pets, Activity activity) {
    this.pets = pets;
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public PetViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_mascotas,parent,false);
    return new PetViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PetViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Pet pet = pets.get(position);
    
    holder.petName.setText(pet.getPetName());
    holder.numberOfLikes.setText(pet.getNumberOfLikes()); //Línea del error
    holder.ivCardview.setImageResource(pet.getFoto());
    holder.ibEmptyBone.setImageResource(R.drawable.dog_bone_48);
    holder.ibStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_48);
    holder.ivFullBone.setImageResource(R.drawable.dog_bone_48_1);

    //Añadimos un listener en la imagen Star, para pasar a la siguiente pantalla
    holder.ibStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intn = new Intent(activity, FavouritePet.class);
            intn.putExtra("nombreMascota",pet.getPetName());
            intn.putExtra("numeroLikes",pet.getNumberOfLikes());
            intn.putExtra("foto",pet.getFoto());
            activity.startActivity(intn);
        }
    });
```

El error en cuestión es el siguiente:

```
08-20 10:23:16.422 9935-9935/es.uclm.mylittlepets E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: es.uclm.mylittlepets, PID: 9935 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getText(ResourcesWrapper.java:52)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4417)
    at es.uclm.mylittlepets.PetAdapter.onBindViewHolder(PetAdapter.java:43)
    at es.uclm.mylittlepets.PetAdapter.onBindViewHolder(PetAdapter.java:19)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5768)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5801)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5037)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4913)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2029)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1414)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:578)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3260)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3069)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3518)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
```

08-20 10:24:02.509 9935-9941/es.uclm.mylittlepets W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.975ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia tu linea a:

```
holder.numberOfLikes.setText(String.valueOf(pet.getNumberOfLikes()));
```

Esto para convertir a String el valor de `pet.getNumberOfLikes()` ya que si se tiene un entero se esta interpretando como un id de recurso, por eso obtienes este error:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0